# How to separate json response in two variables?

Tags: jquery, json

Right now json response looks like

```
["AG","ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA","AU","AUSTRALIA","BR","BRAZIL","CA","CANADA"]
```

i can make it

```
["AG,ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA","AU,AUSTRALIA","BR,BRAZIL","CA,CANADA"]
```

if thas easier to work with or any other style.

what i need is to separate it into two variables one for county code other for country name

```
   ...success: function( json ) {
    $.each(json, function(i, value) {
          $('#country').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
    };  
      });
```

now same variable goes in value and name of option i need to put country code in option and country name in variable.

Comment: It looks like your sending along the two letter abbreviation along with the full country name but not using the abbreviation, do you mean to use it, or can you avoid sending it along altogether?

Answer (score 4):

Why not return them as JSON objects in the first place?  Something like

```
[{"ID":"AG", "Text":"ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA"},{"ID":"AU", "Text":"Australia"}]
```

Then you could do something like

```
$.each( result, function( value ){
    $('#country').append(
        $("<option>").text(value.Text).attr("value", value.Text)
    );
});
```

---

**EDIT:**
The above code assumes you've already converted the data sent from the server into a JavaScript array.  There are two ways to approach that:

1. You can request the data using the [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method and jQuery will parse the return value for you
2. You can parse the data yourself using the [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Either method will take a well formated JSON string and give you back a JavaScript object to work with

Answer (score 1):

**If you go with your 2nd option you can [split](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php) the string as such**

```
var countries = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
$.each(countries, function(i, value) {
    var country = value.split(",");
    $('#country').append($('<option>').text(country[1]).attr('value', country[0]));

};
```

EDIT: You need to parse the JSON string first, so you can use the Array Object and loop through it. See my updated code above.

Comment: What its doing is this
  `<option value="A">G</option>`
breaking two letter country code for value and name

Comment: He doesn't necessarily need to parse it, he could use the [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method and have that happen automatically.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: Yeah it'll just call parseJSON internally :)

Comment: Most likely, but it's one less thing he needs to worry about :).

Answer (score 0):

If you can make it:

```
[["AG","ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA"],["AU","AUSTRALIA"],["BR","BRAZIL"],["CA","CANADA"]]
```

Then you could use this:

```
success: function( json ) {
  $.each(json, function(i, value) {
    $('#country').append($('<option>').text(value[1]).attr('value', value[0]));
  };  
});
```

Comment: my output does not look like this, it double quote everytime i write to json so it looks like 
["[AG,ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA]","[AU,AUSTRALIA]","[BR,BRAZIL]","[CA,CANADA]"]
and prints first letter in option title and in value "["

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take this:

```
var array = ["AG","ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA","AU","AUSTRALIA","BR","BRAZIL","CA","CANADA"];
```

And make it an array of key/value pair objects, you could do something like this:

```
result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 2) {
  result.push({ array[i] : array[i + 1]});
}
```

You'll end up with the equivalent of this in `result`:

```
result = [
  { "AG" : "ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA" },
  { "AU" : "AUSTRALIA" },
  { "BR" : "BRAZIL" },
  { "CA" : "CANADA" }
];
```

---

Update: If all you care about is adding those to the select, you can do it this way:

```
var array = ["AG","ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA","AU","AUSTRALIA","BR","BRAZIL","CA","CANADA"];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 2) {
  // Using this object initializer to build the options has a caching benefit.
  $('#country').append($('<option>', {
    value: array[i],
    text: array[i + 1]
  }));
}
```

For what it's worth, it may be negligible in this case, but this approach is relatively slow.  If you notice performance issues, look into using the `.detach()` method to pull `#country` out of the DOM while the options are being added and then attaching it back at the end.

Comment: what do i do after that i need final solution i dont know jquerry that well

Comment: Updated to give you the solution you're after (I think).