# JSON get form values using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I dont know if i am tired or why i cannot get it right please help what i need is

```
    <script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    getResultsCountry();
}) 

function getResultsCountry() {
  $.ajax({
        url:'suggest_country.html',
        type:'POST',
        data: 'q=',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( json ) {
        $('#country')[0].options.length = 0;
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
            if (value=='<?php echo $country; ?>') {
                $('#country').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value).attr('selected', 'selected'));
            } else {
                $('#country').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
            };
        });
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

Code in external file looks like

```
<?php


   $results = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT country FROM MyTable WHERE country LIKE \'%\' ORDER BY country');

   while( $result = mysql_fetch_array($results) ) {
        $cities = $cities.' short = \''.$result['country'].'\' OR';       
   }

   $cities = substr($cities, 1,strlen($cities)-3);

   $results2 = mysql_query('SELECT full, short FROM `Countries` WHERE '.$cities);
   $json = array();
   while( $result2 = mysql_fetch_array($results2) ) {
        $json[] = $result2['short'].','.$result2['full'];
   }

   echo json_encode( $json );
   mysql_close($db2);
?>
```

Response i am getting is

```
["AG,ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA","AU,AUSTRALIA","BR,BRAZIL","CA,CANADA","KY,CAYMAN ISLANDS","CN,CHINA"]
```

What i need is to fill it in the options for  tag i got this part too, but i cannot make it fill country code AG as value and name as name like

```
<option value="AG">Antigua</option>
```

please break it down for me  i am really confused and tired its been hours of headache.

Comment: I think what's happening is you didn't take the time to follow up on your [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925246/how-to-separate-json-response-in-two-variables) question and just reposted it to see if someone can take your code and fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to split values

```
$.each(json, function(i, value) {
            var arr_values = value.split(',');
            if (value=='<?php echo $country; ?>') {
               $('#country').append($('<option>').text(arr_values[1]).attr('value', arr_values[0]).attr('selected', 'selected'));
            } else {
                $('#country').append($('<option>').text(arr_values[1]).attr('value', arr_values[0])));
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It would make your ajax callback much easier if you didn't have to split your strings..

```
while( $result2 = mysql_fetch_array($results2) ) {
    $json[] = array('short'=>$result2['short'],
                    'full' => $result2['full']
              );
```

}

And then you can parse by

```
$.each(json, function(i, value) {
            if (value['full']=='<?php echo $country; ?>') {
               $('#country').append($('<option>').text(value['full']).attr('value', value['short']).attr('selected', 'selected'));
            } else {
                $('#country').append($('<option>').text(value['short']).attr('value', value['full'])));
            };
        });
```